# The browser sends the data, but does not changing the page at the address /articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, browser

I write form_with on /new page,  when I press the button browser send data(I see it by server and fiddler),but the /new page not redirecting by /articles address.

I try to restart server and another browser, but change nothing. I try for_form :articles, url: '/articles', for_form @article, url: articles_path and some variants yet.

articles_controller.rb
In ArticlesController I create new article

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        render plain: params[:article].inspect
    end
end
```

In new.html.erb I use form builder form_with

```
<%= form_with(model: @article, method: :post, url: articles_path) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

rails server display it

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-03-22 15:58:47 +0300
Processing by ArticlesController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "article"=>{"title"=>"", "text"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 442)
```

console Firefox

`Error: Form responses must redirect to another location`

Comment: I find decision.<%= form_with(model: @article, local: true, data: { turbo: false },  url: articles_path) do |f| %>

Comment: because you didn't redirect, you need to render an error response: `render plain: params[:article].inspect, status: :unprocessable_entity`